# Calculate the volume under the function $f(x,y) = xy$ on a region $R$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume

[image]

I am trying to find the volume underneath $f(x,y) = xy$ on the region $R$ shown in the picture.

I tried integral on polar coordinates:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_1^4 \left(r\cos\theta\right)\left(r\sin\theta\right)\, dr \, d\theta$$

but this doesn't give one of the answer choices so I don't know what is wrong.

I tried also multiplying by one of the random things you have to add on the end of polar coordinate integrals like $r$ or $r^2$ but it doesn't work

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_1^4 \left(r\cos\theta\right)\left(r\sin\theta\right)r \, dr \, d\theta$$

and this doesn't work either

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_1^4 \left(r\cos\theta\right)\left(r\sin\theta\right)r^2 \, dr \, d\theta$$

None of them give answers that are one of the four choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct one is
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_1^4 \left(r\cos\theta\right)\left(r\sin\theta\right)r \, dr \, d\theta = \frac{255}{8}
$$

where $rdrd\theta$ is the differential area element and $(r\cos\theta)(r\sin\theta)$ is the height of the differential area element.

Comment: that's not one of the answer choices ... does that mean the question is wrong?

Comment: I checked it multiple times. Unless I'm completely missing something. Please leave a message if you find my answer is wrong.

Comment: yeah i also got 255/8 ... question must be wrong then?

Comment: That's what I think too

Comment: Maybe check the errata of the source of this question.